# Biq query - Date conversion function - Error will using Date format of %D format

Tags: google-bigquery, cloud

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYhXl.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B00Dl.png)

While trying to use the Date_format function with the '%D' format Date type, I am getting an error while running in biq query console

I am expecting the parsing result for the above query

Answer (score 0):

`FORMAT_DATE` function takes in two parameters. The first one is
the format string that defines how the output should be formatted and the second is the date you want to format. You can supply the second parameter as a string in format "YYYY-MM-DD" which will then automatically converted to a date value.

Here's the full example:

```sql
SELECT FORMAT_DATE("%D", "2020-01-20")
```